# Inserting no values to columns causing error on MySQL database

Tags: mysql, null, insert

I exported a local database in XAMPP which was on MariaDB to a online server which has MySQL on it. Now when inserting to tables, unless I provide `" "` to string values or '0' to boolean variables, I cannot insert into it. While working locally on XAMPP, I didn't have to specify any values I didn't want to insert, and it would automatically initialize to 0 in the case for booleans and simply no values for strings. In server, I have to allow NULL value or pass something like `" "` for the query to work. how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the same table structure locally and on your server ? Especially default values and nullable ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same DB that I exported from XAMPP on my server. I was having this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149100/pdo-queries-works-locally-not-on-server Then I was trying various insert queries when I realized it fails unless I provide these null/0/" "  values.